# Gradle task with 2 ant targets - trying to combine ant targets to speed up execution time

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, ant, build.gradle, mapper

I currently have a Gradle Task that uses 2 ant targets (copy and move). These 2 ant tasks give me the right results. However, I was wondering if it is possible to join them into one ant target to speed up the execution time and to reduce the amount of code.

I have tried to do that with 2 mappers, but I can only use one mapper apparently. I have tried to use chainedmapper and compositemapper, but the results were not what I expected.

### What I want

I have some files that I need to change all their extension `(.icls -> .xml)`, and I have one file that I want to rename `(ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA -> ChroMATERIAL)`

```
Starting file name                    final file name
------------------                    ---------------
ChroMATERIAL - Darker.icls        ->  ChroMATERIAL - Darker.xml
ChroMATERIAL - Darcula.icls       ->  ChroMATERIAL - Darcula.xml
ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.icls   ->  ChroMATERIAL.xml
```

The code below is what I was trying to go for originally before I got an error message. The code at the very end is my workaround that I currently use.

EDIT: I do prefer an ant-based grade task. I have looked at pure ant based files that appear to allow for multiple mappers and that is what I think I need, but I have not been able to get something similar working.

### What I Tried

```
task syncFiles {

    doLast {

        // Sync files from IntelliJ's color scheme and rename extension
        ant.copy(todir: sourceDir) {
            ant.fileset(dir: intelliJColorSchemeDir)

            // NOTE: This is an error message. Can only have one mapper!
            ant.mapper(type: "glob", from: "*.icls", to: "*.xml")
            ant.mapper(type: "glob", from: "ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.xml", to: "ChroMATERIAL.xml")    
        }
    }
}
```

### My Current Implementation

This is what I want to turn into one ant task with 2 mappers. This I believe can be turned into slimmer code that only calls `ant` once. I want this code to execute a little faster, too.

```
task syncFiles {

    doLast {

        // Sync files from IntelliJ's color scheme and rename extension
        ant.copy(todir: sourceDir) {
            ant.fileset(dir: intelliJColorSchemeDir)
            ant.mapper(type: "glob", from: "*.icls", to: "*.xml")
        }

        // Rename one specific file. I want this mapper to be joined with the above mapper
        ant.move(todir: sourceDir) {
            ant.fileset(dir: sourceDir)
            ant.mapper(type: "glob", from: "ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.xml", to: "ChroMATERIAL.xml")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With staying with the original question and providing an Ant-based solution, the following code seems to be the cleanest. There might be other types of composite mappers that perform better, but this is what I could come up with.

```
    ant.copy(todir: sourceDir) {
        ant.fileset(dir: intelliJColorSchemeDir)
        ant.firstmatchmapper {
            ant.globmapper(from: "ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.icls", to: "ChroMATERIAL.xml")
            ant.globmapper(from: "*.icls", to: "*.xml")
        }
    }
```

Things I like about it. The code is very clean and does not use strange syntax such as regex. It also combines the mappers into one block. Lastly, it uses Ant like I originally wanted.

Performing some quick tests seem to show very little change in execution time, but I have reported some of the quickest execution times for this task with the above code. Don't know if that is a fluke or if it is slightly faster.

Edit:

Here is the clear and concise version of using Gradle only...

```
into sourceDir
from intelliJColorSchemeDir, {
    rename 'ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.icls','ChroMATERIAL.xml'  // Edit: moved to top and changed file extension.
    rename '(.*)\\.icls$', '$1.xml'

}
```

This code is actually faster on every run it appears.

Comment: I'd put `rename 'ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.icls','ChroMATERIAL.xml'` first rather than letting it be renamed twice. You also don't need `include '**'`

Answer (score 1):

```
task syncFiles(type: Copy) {
    into sourceDir
    with copySpec {
       from intelliJColorSchemeDir
       include '**/ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.icls'
       rename '.*', 'ChroMATERIAL.xml'
    }
    with copySpec {
       from intelliJColorSchemeDir
       exclude '**/ChroMATERIAL IntelliJ IDEA.icls'
       rename '(.*)\\.icls$', '$1.xls'
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally did do a Grade Copy task. I changed it for some reason. I will have to look at why. I really dislike the dotIndex and and ext variables. They really clutter up the code. I think my original code was similar but much cleaner. Do you know how to do this with gradles ant task? Part of this question was also to learn how to do ant tasks in Gradle.

Comment: Updated, second attempt is cleaner

Comment: The code is still too much. I posted a code snippet below of using Ant that is very concise.

Comment: Gradle's Copy task has the benefit of up-to-date checking which you won't get from your ant version (unless you set the task inputs/outputs explicitly). Net result is that my version will be skipped if nothing has changed since the last copy, yours will always do the copy.

Comment: I added a Gradle only Copy task that is really fast and concise.

Comment: The answer was OK, but you were very helpful and I learned a lot from your comments. Ordering of rename. You can provide UP-TO-DATE functionality to Ant code with explicit inputs and outputs, copySpec, etc.